# Unable to add an action to my controller from storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, swift

This has been asked before but as you can see from the picture a simple control+drag from the story board to the controller doesn't work. I made a new Cocoa Class subclass of UIViewController. After I try to hook up my Map View to it and it simply does not respond.

[image]

Comment: A map view doesn't have an "action"; it is not a button. So it's hard to see what you're after here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have most likely not set your View Controller's class to your newly created class.

You can do this by going to your View Controller's Identity Inspector and changing the class from `UIViewController` to `MapViewController`.

You'll then be able to connect UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to set the class of the view controller you have in the storyboard. Make sure the class is set to "MapViewController"

Here is where you set it :
[Setting the Class of a VC in Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ws0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's your own issue.

1) Storyboard on left side

2) class(`ViewController`) should be automatic in right side.

See image below:
[image]